# File upload in FormView (as a parameter)

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, formview

I have FormView in three states: ItemTemplate, EditItemTemplate and InsertItemTemplate.
In ItemTemaplate, I've made possible to download file from database in a outer manner:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" OnCommand="GetBenefitPdf" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("benefit_id") %>' Text="Get PDF" />
```

and:

```
protected void GetBenefitPdf(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    int benefit_id = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
    Response.Redirect("GetPdf.aspx?id=" + benefit_id + "&page=ManageBenefits.aspx");
}
```

But I also need to upload a file (attachment) in InsertItemTemplate and EditItemTemplate.
In both of the above I've made:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="filedata" runat="server" />
```

But the SQL commands (parameters are given) are making an exception:

> String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated.

How should I handle this?

EDIT: SQL is given:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceManageBenefits" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:validConnectionString %>"
SelectCommand="SELECT [min_buyers], [active], [benefit_id], [name], [description], [price], [avail_pcs], [type], [months], [link], [family], [start_date], [end_date], [months_cancel], [price_month], [price_full], [payroll], [payroll_add], [payroll_sub], [price_all], [labor_id], [filedata] FROM [benefits]"
FilterExpression=" type='{0}' " ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [benefits] WHERE [benefit_id] = @original_benefit_id AND (([min_buyers] = @original_min_buyers) OR ([min_buyers] IS NULL AND @original_min_buyers IS NULL)) AND [active] = @original_active AND (([name] = @original_name) OR ([name] IS NULL AND @original_name IS NULL)) AND (([description] = @original_description) OR ([description] IS NULL AND @original_description IS NULL)) AND (([price] = @original_price) OR ([price] IS NULL AND @original_price IS NULL)) AND (([avail_pcs] = @original_avail_pcs) OR ([avail_pcs] IS NULL AND @original_avail_pcs IS NULL)) AND (([type] = @original_type) OR ([type] IS NULL AND @original_type IS NULL)) AND (([months] = @original_months) OR ([months] IS NULL AND @original_months IS NULL)) AND (([link] = @original_link) OR ([link] IS NULL AND @original_link IS NULL)) AND (([family] = @original_family) OR ([family] IS NULL AND @original_family IS NULL)) AND (([start_date] = @original_start_date) OR ([start_date] IS NULL AND @original_start_date IS NULL)) AND (([end_date] = @original_end_date) OR ([end_date] IS NULL AND @original_end_date IS NULL)) AND (([months_cancel] = @original_months_cancel) OR ([months_cancel] IS NULL AND @original_months_cancel IS NULL)) AND (([price_month] = @original_price_month) OR ([price_month] IS NULL AND @original_price_month IS NULL)) AND (([price_full] = @original_price_full) OR ([price_full] IS NULL AND @original_price_full IS NULL)) AND (([payroll] = @original_payroll) OR ([payroll] IS NULL AND @original_payroll IS NULL)) AND (([payroll_add] = @original_payroll_add) OR ([payroll_add] IS NULL AND @original_payroll_add IS NULL)) AND (([payroll_sub] = @original_payroll_sub) OR ([payroll_sub] IS NULL AND @original_payroll_sub IS NULL)) AND (([price_all] = @original_price_all) OR ([price_all] IS NULL AND @original_price_all IS NULL)) AND (([labor_id] = @original_labor_id) OR ([labor_id] IS NULL AND @original_labor_id IS NULL)) AND (([filedata] = @original_filedata) OR ([filedata] IS NULL AND @original_filedata IS NULL))" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [benefits] ([min_buyers], [active], [name], [description], [price], [avail_pcs], [type], [months], [link], [family], [start_date], [end_date], [months_cancel], [price_month], [price_full], [payroll], [payroll_add], [payroll_sub], [price_all]), [labor_id], [filedata] VALUES (@min_buyers, @active, @name, @description, @price, @avail_pcs, @type, @months, @link, @family, @start_date, @end_date, @months_cancel, @price_month, @price_full, @payroll, @payroll_add, @payroll_sub, @price_all, @labor_id, @filedata)" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [benefits] SET [min_buyers] = @min_buyers, [active] = @active, [name] = @name, [description] = @description, [price] = @price, [avail_pcs] = @avail_pcs, [type] = @type, [months] = @months, [link] = @link, [family] = @family, [start_date] = @start_date, [end_date] = @end_date, [months_cancel] = @months_cancel, [price_month] = @price_month, [price_full] = @price_full, [payroll] = @payroll, [payroll_add] = @payroll_add, [payroll_sub] = @payroll_sub, [price_all] = @price_all, [labor_id] = @labor_id, [filedata] = @filedata WHERE [benefit_id] = @original_benefit_id AND (([min_buyers] = @original_min_buyers) OR ([min_buyers] IS NULL AND @original_min_buyers IS NULL)) AND [active] = @original_active AND (([name] = @original_name) OR ([name] IS NULL AND @original_name IS NULL)) AND (([description] = @original_description) OR ([description] IS NULL AND @original_description IS NULL)) AND (([price] = @original_price) OR ([price] IS NULL AND @original_price IS NULL)) AND (([avail_pcs] = @original_avail_pcs) OR ([avail_pcs] IS NULL AND @original_avail_pcs IS NULL)) AND (([type] = @original_type) OR ([type] IS NULL AND @original_type IS NULL)) AND (([months] = @original_months) OR ([months] IS NULL AND @original_months IS NULL)) AND (([link] = @original_link) OR ([link] IS NULL AND @original_link IS NULL)) AND (([family] = @original_family) OR ([family] IS NULL AND @original_family IS NULL)) AND (([start_date] = @original_start_date) OR ([start_date] IS NULL AND @original_start_date IS NULL)) AND (([end_date] = @original_end_date) OR ([end_date] IS NULL AND @original_end_date IS NULL)) AND (([months_cancel] = @original_months_cancel) OR ([months_cancel] IS NULL AND @original_months_cancel IS NULL)) AND (([price_month] = @original_price_month) OR ([price_month] IS NULL AND @original_price_month IS NULL)) AND (([price_full] = @original_price_full) OR ([price_full] IS NULL AND @original_price_full IS NULL)) AND (([payroll] = @original_payroll) OR ([payroll] IS NULL AND @original_payroll IS NULL)) AND (([payroll_add] = @original_payroll_add) OR ([payroll_add] IS NULL AND @original_payroll_add IS NULL)) AND (([payroll_sub] = @original_payroll_sub) OR ([payroll_sub] IS NULL AND @original_payroll_sub IS NULL)) AND (([price_all] = @original_price_all) OR ([price_all] IS NULL AND @original_price_all IS NULL)) AND (([labor_id] = @original_labor_id) OR ([labor_id] IS NULL AND @original_labor_id IS NULL)) AND (([filedata] = @original_filedata) OR ([filedata] IS NULL AND @original_filedata IS NULL))">
```

Also there are parameters:

```
<asp:Parameter Name="original_filedata" Type="Byte" />
<asp:Parameter Name="filedata" Type="Byte" />
```

Comment: So you have a SQL issue but post the C# code without the SQL?  I am guessing that you need to make the column in the database you are inserting into longer (increase the length), but there is no way to tell with what you have above.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I've edited the question. The column is varbinary(MAX) in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I solved it.
The solution is to use:

```
<asp:Parameter Name="original_filedata" DbType="Binary" />
<asp:Parameter Name="filedata" DbType="Binary" />
```

and also make OnInserting and OnUpdating command:

```
protected void Attach(object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
{
    var file = ((FileUpload)FormViewManageBenefits.FindControl("filedata")).FileBytes;
    e.Command.Parameters["@filedata"].Value = file;
}
```